# Dealing with Order by CASE Statements and NULL value

Tags: sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by, case

I'd like to custom order by based on a column.  If the column value is NULL or '' (empty string), then I want to display that row first.  SQL Server does not like the following:

```
ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN  ISNULL(SendDate.ValidTo, '') = ''
        THEN NULL
        END
```

or

```
ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN  ISNULL(SendDate.ValidTo, '') = ''
        THEN ISNULL(SendDate.ValidTo, '') = ''
        END
```

Is it acceptable to do following?:

```
ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN  ISNULL(SendDate.ValidTo, '') = ''
        THEN SendDate.ValidTo
        END
```

Comment: The problem with all those CASE statements is they don't have an ELSE clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could assign a number on which to order by the different outcomes of your `CASE`-statement, like so:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COALESCE(SendDate.ValidTo,'') = '' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Comment: would this order by null / blank values first and then desc or asc?

Comment: By default ascending, but you could add `, SendDate.ValidTo DESC` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I realized, I could have just done the following:

```
ORDER BY
        ISNULL(SendDate.ValidTo, '1900-01-01')
```

Comment: This would order your empty strings before your NULLS.  If you want to treat them equally then you should use Aquillo's answer.